# How to disable monaco-decorations-style in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable monaco-decorations-style in vscode.

It overwrite my custom theme.

Help me. thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In user pref basis, there is `explorer.decorations.colors` in the `settings.json`:

```
// Controls if file decorations should use colors.
"explorer.decorations.colors": true
```

Setting this to `false` makes text in explorer pane uniform, regardless the SCM state.